# Extract string from a large paragraph

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract string which follows the pattern

If input is like this

https://www.facebook.com/tajmahal&sa=U&amp;

**output**

https://www.facebook.com/tajmahal

If input is like this

https://www.facebook.com/tajmahal+taj+mahal+facebook&tbo=1&amp;

**output**

https://www.facebook.com/tajmahal

That is i only want to get the  string removing unnecessary strings.

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/[^>]*>([^<]+)</a>");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
  String pageid = "";

  while (m.find())
  {
      Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("href=\"https://www.facebook.com/(.*?)\"");
      Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(m.group(0));
      String url = null;
      if (m1.find())
      {
          url = m1.group(1);
```

Comment: and what have you tried? show us some effort.

Comment: You forgot to show what you have already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like

```
https://www\.facebook\.com/[^&+]+
```

After the `/` you want chars that are not `&` or `+`

Maybe you have other requirements about what can be a "delimiter character" in your input, if so add them inside the `[^&+]`

To do this you probably want study how "character classes" work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String str = input.replaceAll("^([^&+]+).*", "$1");
```